# Python not all in operation

Tags: python, set

How do I check if a list is a subset of a bigger list.

i.e.

`a = [1,2,3]` is a subset of `b = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Can I do something like

```
if a all in b
```

Comment: Do you really mean "set"? In other words, does the order of the elements matter?

Comment: This is why I love python, you practically answered your own question, "a.issubset(b)".  Which raises the question, why don't we have a 'issubset' method on list?

Comment: @monkut: how do you define subset for sequences?

Comment: @Byers: No I mean a list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> a = set([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> a.issubset(b)
True
```

or

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> all(map(lambda x: x in b, a))
True
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 9]
>>> all(map(lambda x: x in b, a))
False
```

or (if the number of elements is important)

```
>>> a = [1, 1, 2, 3]
>>> all(map(lambda x: a.count(x) <= b.count(x), a))
False
```

Comment: Still, it has problem with duplicates - assuming that we want to test for e.g. two 1's from 'a' being present in 'b'

Comment: Indeed... I have edit the answer to provide an alternative solution (not optimized)

Answer (score 12):

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset

```
set(a).issubset(set(b))
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this will NOT account for repeated elements in the list, e.g. if a = [1, 1, 2, 3] and b = [1, 2, 3, 4], this will still evaluate true.

Comment: @ezod: Right, but if Peter says "set" I think this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

mostly like the other answers, but I do prefer the generator syntax here, seems more natural and it's lazily evaluated:

```
if all(x in b for x in a):
    pass
```

if you care about the number of repeated elements, this option seems nice, and you could optimize it sorting c and using bisect:

```
def all_in(a, b)
    try:
        c = b[:]
        for x in a: c.remove[x]
        return True
    except:
        return False
```